# Quadcopter Hovering Problem

Tags: quadcopter

My quadcopter can lift off the ground, but it kinds of circles around. Here is my video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rxjpwhbgiw0

Anyone helps me?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1209/350

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind is an error associated with the sensors, have you tuned the sensors? It seems that the sensor is reading an angle when the craft is level which makes it correct continuously when it's level.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but...it is normal... you are flying in ground effect so it is normal that it is very hard to keep it stable in one point (I suppose you are driving it with some controllers).

Give more power and lift on about 0.5 m or something like that and see what happen. 
To avoid destroying your quadrotor I can suggest you to put a cable (or better a spring) from the ceiling of your garage to the C.G. of the quadrotor to keep it balanced. At worse you destroy one propeller..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the white blocks under the propellers?

I understand that you use them as somewhere to safely land, but they seem a bit far from aerodynamic. A quadrotor flies because of the air it gets to move under it, but you are placing a white box just in the middle of the way of that air.

The sound that quadrotor makes just to move a few cm from the ground should be a hint.

The blocks are a good idea, in my opinion, but they should be placed somewhere else, try and move them towards the centre, far from the propellers influence. Make them a bit smaller if you have to, but let the air flow free. Cut them to a more rounded shape if you will.

If you have some doubts about my answer, no better way of proving me wrong (or right) than running your own wind test. Get some smoke (anyway you want) go through the propellers, fix the quadrotor to ground and record the results of how the air flows around the blocks. The smoother (a perfect straight line being the best) the lines of air are, the better the flight can be. A vortex means a low pressure under your vehicle, which is the opposite of what you want.

Good luck! Please, show us the results.

Answer (score 0):

You are flying in the near of ground so the [Ground effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_effect_(aerodynamics)) applies. Test flight in an altitude of min. 0.5 meter height.

Also if this doesn't help, then there could be that there is a bit more weight on one side of the multicopter, to counteract it set an integral (I) value for the P**I**D controller of the Multicopter. The I value will help the Quadrotor to remain in the required position (horizontal while hover).